# Compiler support of GNU Statement Expression

Tags: c, visual-c++, compiler-construction, c99

Which modern compilers support the Gnu Statement expression (C and C++ languages). What versions should I have to use a statement expressions?

Statement expression is smth like `({ code; code; retval })`:

```
int b=56;
int c=({int a; a=sin(b); a;});
```

I already know some such compilers:

- GCC >=3
- Clang/LLVM >= 3.0.0
- Intel C++ Compiler >= 6.0 (Linux version, [check page 4](http://scc.ustc.edu.cn/zlsc/lenovo_1800/200910/W020100308600680463493.pdf); bit [limited](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/cdiag1487/))
- Sun Studio >= 12 ([New Language Extensions](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/c_type.html#Using%20Statement%20Expressions%7Coutline))
- IBM XL for z/OS ([marked as IBM extension](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r11/topic/com.ibm.zos.r11.cbclx01/statement_expressions.htm))
- Open64 (as it uses *osprey-gcc* frontend)

This compiler seems not to support this (i'm unsure):

- MS Visual C++

PS. some C/C++ compilers are listed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_compilers) but I interested only in mature compilers, that are used widely (e.g not a tcc or turbo c)

Answer (score 2):

[The PathScale® EKOPath Compiler Suite](http://www.pathscale.com/ekopath-compiler-suite)

It support gnu99 with "[−std=gnu99](http://www.pathscale.com/docs/pathCC.html)"

Answer (score 1):

The Intel C++ Compiler does not support statement expressions, even the last version that I know, version 13.0.

Comment: But [the page](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/composerxe/en-us/2011Update/cpp/lin/bldaps_cls/common/bldaps_gcc_compat_comm.htm) says "*Statement expressions are supported, except the following are prohibited inside them:*".. and [this, page4](http://scc.ustc.edu.cn/zlsc/lenovo_1800/200910/W020100308600680463493.pdf) says it is true since Intel C++ Compiler version 6.0

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comment of my previous answer, the Intel Compiler does support the statement expressions. But the emulation by Intel of that GNU extension is not complete, in C++. The following code is taken from CGAL-4.0 (http://www.cgal.org/):

```
#include <cassert>

struct A {
  int* p;

  A(int i) : p(new int(i)) {}
  ~A() { delete p; }
  int value() const { return *p;}
};

int main()
{
  int i = __extension__ ({ int j = 2; j+j; });
  assert(i == 4);

  // The Intel Compiler complains with the following error:
  // "error: destructible entities are not allowed inside of a statement
  // expression"
  // See http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/cdiag1487/
  i = __extension__ ({ A a(2); A b(3); a.value() + b.value(); });

  assert(i == 5);
  return 0;
}
```

A comment in the code even give the error returned by the Intel Compiler, tested with version 11, 12, or 13.

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/cdiag1487/