# Objective-C syntax questions

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, static, objective-c-blocks

I've found this code on this blog http://themainthread.com/blog/2014/02/building-a-universal-app.html

```
static void initSimpleView(SimpleView *self) {
    // Configure default properties of your view and initialize any subviews
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    self.imageView = ({
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [self addSubview:imageView];
        imageView;
    });

    self.label = ({
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [self addSubview:label];
        label;
    });
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        initSimpleView(self);
    }
    return self;
}
```

How does it work? 
What is the meaning of `static void initWithSimpleView(SimpleView *self)`?
Why are `imageView` and `label` initialized in some kind of block?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code declares a C function named `initSimpleView`.  The name `initSimpleView` is only visible within the file, because it is declared `static`.

The `({ ... })` is a GNU C extension called a “statement expression”.  You can find more details about this usage [in this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19732070/77567).