# Assigning a variable value from an Objective-C Block

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

In Swift I can give a variable a value using an anonymous closure:

```
let thumbnailImageView: UIImageView = {
   let imageView = UIImageView()
   imageView.backGroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
   return imageView;
}

addSubView(thumbnailImageView)
thumbnailImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)
```

I am trying to do the same in Obj-C, but this results in an error when adding the subview and setting its frame:

```
UIImageView* (^thumbnailImageView)(void) = ^(void){
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    return imageView;
};

[self addSubview:thumbnailImageView];

thumbnailImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
```

Comment: You need to run (may not be the correct term) the block like: `thumbnailImageView()`.

Comment: using `[self addSubview:thumbnailImageView()];` ???

Comment: Your Swift code doesn't compile. You also don't really need to use a Block for this. You're basically looking for [a statement expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732070/objective-c-declare-vars-with).

Comment: that is not block. blocks are written with square brackets

Comment: @GeneCode: _"blocks are written with square brackets"_ What? No, they're not. The ObjC code here correctly creates a Block.

Comment: You can use anonymous closures in Obj-C but since there is no type inferring, it won't simplify code, it would actually end up a big mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to write in Objective-C with Swift syntax. The Swift example describes a lazily initialized variable, while Objective-C one declares a simple block that returns `UIImageView`. You'd need to call the block with

```
[self addSubview:thumbnailImageView()];
```

However, in this case using the block to initialize a variable makes little sense. If you're looking for lazily initialized properties, it would look like this in Objective-C

```
@interface YourClass : Superclass

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView* imageView;

@end

@synthesize imageView = _imageView;

- (UIImageView*)imageView
{
    if (!_imageView) {
        // init _imageView here
    }
    return _imageView;
}
```