# Understanding hlist_bl_for_each_entry_rcu macro in Linux Kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel

While browsing Linux kernel source, I found `hlist_bl_for_each_entry_rcu` macro.Below is its definition

```
for (pos = hlist_bl_first_rcu(head);                            \
                pos &&                                                  \
                ({ tpos = hlist_bl_entry(pos, typeof(*tpos), member); 1; }); \
                pos = rcu_dereference_raw(pos->next))
```

This macro is used in `__d_lookup()` to get the dentry. What I do not understand is the line

`({ tpos = hlist_bl_entry(pos, typeof(*tpos), member); 1; });`

It gets the tpos. What is the use of 1 here ? How to understand this condition in the for loop ?

Comment: That line is uses a [GCC extension known as a statement expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440021). Think of that line as a function whose return value is always `1`.

Comment: @user3386109- it means the condition in for loop is "pos && 1" irrespective of value of tpos ?

Comment: Yes. Due to [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), `tpos` will only be updated when `pos` is not NULL. And the body of the loop will *always* execute when `pos` is not NULL. The loop condition doesn't check whether `tpos` is NULL. Either it's guaranteed that `tpos` is always valid when `pos` is not NULL, or the body of the loop needs to handle the case where `tpos` is NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were writing it macroless, it would probably look like this:

```
for (pos = hlist_bl_first_rcu(head); pos; pos = rcu_dereference_raw(pos->next)) {
    tpos = hlist_bl_entry(pos, typeof(*tpos), member);

    /* do something with pos and tpos */

}
```

For the macro, you would want to move `tpos = hlist_bl_entry(pos, typeof(*tpos), member);` into the `for (...)`, so the user only has to supply the `for` block. In the macroless version, you want `tpos`' value set every time `pos` is non-NULL, thus you add it in the loop condition after a `pos &&`:

```
pos && (tpos = hlist_bl_entry(pos, typeof(*tpos), member))
```

but now tops non-nullness becomes a loop condition, so you tell C to [ignore the return value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator):

```
pos && ((tpos = hlist_bl_entry(pos, typeof(*tpos), member)), 1)
```

but kernel code is GNU C anyway, so you may use [statement expressions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) instead:

```
pos && ({ tpos = hlist_bl_entry(pos, typeof(*tpos), member); 1; })
```